How to Add Both Bitbucket and GitHub as Remote Repositories for a Single Git Project and Push to Both?
I'm working on a project where I need to use both Bitbucket and GitHub as remote repositories. I want to be able to push my changes to both platforms simultaneously. I already have a Git repository set up and I am able to push to GitHub, but now I need to add Bitbucket and push to both repositories.
Here are the steps I've taken so far

Initialized the Git repository locally

Added GitHub as a remote repository and have been pushing changes successfully.


git remote add origin https://github.com/username/repository.git
git push -u origin main


https://stackoverflow.com/questions/849308/how-can-i-pull-push-from-multiple-remote-locations Found in https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bgit%5D+multiple+remotes
